# Uncaught Reference Error: $ajax not defined at HtlmInputElement.<anonymous>

Tags: jquery, ajax, referenceerror

I am getting

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ajax is not defined"

I am new to web development. Other jquery functions work, but ajax is not defined. I am not using the slim version as far as I can tell. Is there any way browser is loading it? I am attaching minimum code.

I have tried local version of jquery in my "static" section.
Also other links to jquery from jquery.com website and microsoft cdn.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#UpdateId").on('click', function(){
                    $ajax({
                        data : {
                            Name    : $('#NameId').val(),
                        },
                        method : 'POST',
                        url : '/update'
                    })
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data name = "partupdate">
            <label for="User"> Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="NameId" name="Name" size = 10>
            <input id ="UpdateId" type="button" name="flag" value="Update">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using the following. It should not be the slim version. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> I still get the error. Do you have any suggestion for a link?

Comment: Missing a dot...it's `$.ajax()`  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed my error. I am really thankful. spent a couple of hours trying to find the cause.

Comment: FYI slim version doesn't include ajax